# How to check whether array element is defined or not in twig file?

Tags: php, twig

I am trying to access array but it is not getting accessed.
in my config.yml following is my array :

```
abc : [xyz]
```

and in another file i am writing following code to access abc array.

```
 {% if abc[0] is defined) %}
then do something
  {% endif %}
```

but somehow its not working. please help me out i am newbie in this.

Comment: At this point i'm failing to see why you are trying to use Array type when you could just use string instead

Comment: because my array can have multiple elements

Comment: Did one of the answer solved your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Based on comments I would recommend using foreach loop instead and define your ifs based on index values. Something like this:

```
{% for abcs in abc %}
    {% if (loop.index == 0) %}
         then do something
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

BR's

Comment: in second line instead of loop we have to write abc right?

Comment: Nope. loop.index is correct. Here is the documentation - http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/for.html

Comment: @user2831723 You can use `{% if loop.start %}`, it's simpler. (note that your code has a typo, `)` does not have opening parenthesis)

Answer (score 0):

It depends if the variable is always declared or not:

#### If the variable is always declared and the array can be empty

```
{% if abc is not empty %}
    {# then do something #}
{% endif %}
```

`<variable> is not empty` in Twig is equivalent to `!empty($variable)` in PHP. When an array is provided, `is not empty` will check there is a value and/or a value in the array.

[`empty` test in Twig documentation](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tests/empty.html).

#### If the variable is not always declared

Check that the `abc` variable is declared and not empty:

```
{% if (abc is declared) and (abc is not empty) %}
    {# then do something #}
{% endif %}
```

`<variable> is declared` in Twig is equivalent to `isset($variable)` in PHP.

[`defined` test in Twig documentation](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tests/defined.html).